# Quoted text inline with the rest using code tags is bad. Why?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting, markdown

This might seem silly, but maybe I'm not the only one. So hear me out.

[Lightness Races in Orbit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/560648/lightness-races-in-orbit) just [edited an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24238375/phantomjs-running-render-after-loading-the-page-but-loading-never-fires/24240277?noredirect=1#comment38022309_24240277) of mine, and commented:

> Please don't use code tags for emphasis or quotation; code tags are
>   for *code* (or other verbatim technical stuff).

But then I thought about why I used the inline-code syntax at all. And I realized that I used it as an alternative to the normal quoting, because it (a) allows you to put the quote inline with the rest of the text and (b) looks the same (there's no syntax highlighting in inline-code. I knew that beforehand).

And that still makes a lot of sense to me. inline code is usually technical jargon or very short pieces of code you want to emphesize. If I want to use inline-quotes, it's usually the same situation (or I don't want to put it right before a code block so it won't be confusing).

It's a style-decision more than anything, but I think it deserves some attention (seeing as how SO moderators will spend their time fixing it). So can we decide to allow that? What do you guys think? Am I the only one who ever used it like that or what?

No! this isn't a duplicate! I'm not asking why are we not using the code block to emphasis *any* text. It obviously shouldn't be abused like that, and I'm not talking about that. I'm talking specifically about using quotes, like citing documentation about functions, methods or whathaveyou that it just makes sense to keep inline for whatever reason.

Comment: Generally don't emphasis - to understand a question you probably need to read all of it not just an emphasised part which is what emphasis suggests the reader does. Changing style breaks up reading and makes it harder to read

Comment: @unit3524344 but it's not an exact duplicate. I'm talking about technical quotes that explain a method or function (like the one in the link). Of course you shouldn't use it for any emphasis

Comment: @Mark I don't agree that breaking it up makes it hard to read. For normal emphasis, I usually prefer **bold** or *italic* which are enough. But when I'm quoting something that makes sense to leave inline, I want to make it stand out as a quote (for the same reasons that there are quote-blocks)

Comment: I remember commenting on the answer to that question in reference to code formatting being used for inline quotations, Took long enough for it to finally come up in a question of its own,

Comment: FWIW I do use backticks to delimit quotes in comments, when I'm quoting the thing I'm commenting on, but that's the only exception I'd make. Either use a proper quote block or just use the quotation marks that the English language gave you!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I do too. It makes sense. Don't you agree that it make it more consistent to use it in posts too? Again - technical jargon and quotes that make sense. Not long quotes (we have blocks for that) or anything that can be better formatted with italics

Comment: @yuvi: Nah, not really. That we do it in comments is a hack and not an excuse to do it where the comment system limitation doesn't apply. Reading prose in fixed-width is tiresome and shouldn't be forced on me. Write prose in normal text where possible.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit maybe we should add a `<q>` tag for inline quotes? So we don't need to rely on hacks

Comment: @yuvi: I'd quite like to see that. Not because I think they'll be good in questions/answers (I actually think they'll be _harmful_ there) but because it'd be so useful in comments. We can only italic/bold/code format quotes in comments at the moment and it's a bit limiting. Then again, comments are second-class citizens so we should care quite little about them (which is why I let myself off my little exception).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Using code spans in comments is just as dirty as doing it in a post—there are better ways to format your comments for readability. Your comment of _«just use the quotation marks that the English language gave you»_ should apply to comments as well, but be aware that you have lots of typographical tools at your disposal without bludgeoning readers. For example [guillemets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillemet) are quite useful when nesting quotations and proper use of other markers like semicolons and dashes are usually sufficient to make a comment easily readable.

Comment: @Caleb: I agree and, actually, after engaging on this question, I'm going to stop doing it in comments.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Today I ran across somebody (who will go un-named) on SE formatting their comments by pasting the quoted text un-delineated in any way and injecting their commentary by putting it in code spans. I died a little inside. It took me a while to cross reference everything and figure out who was even saying what! Some people forget that the point of writing and posting online is _to communicate something to someone else_. Unless you purpose to create an echo chamber, the typographical conventions most widely recognized by your readers are the best! </end rant>

Comment: @Caleb: Sir i know( per ur previous comment). sometimes ppl write `Comments` in strange ways!!

Comment: It might be worth [a link to our sister-site here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4720/color-of-certain-elements-in-main-site-doesnt-match-up-with-the-rest-of-the-pag/4722#4722) - english.stackexchange has had this problem and good points are made. Obviously it's a little different to there where backticks are never useful, but it's valid for use cases outside of code, like this.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Code formatting is quite obviously not intended for use as quoting. The fixed-width font is of course for ease of reading code, and the coloured background is for a separation between prose and code that is simply not pertinent for quotations.

When writing quotes, you can do it like "this", or like "*this*", or like:

> this

But when you do it like `this` you make my OCD hurt and my edit trigger finger twitch. It's simply the wrong tool for the job. I don't really understand how anyone could want to do that without getting a headache!

Reading prose in fixed-width is tiresome and shouldn't be forced on me. Write prose in normal text where possible.

In general (as with, say, HTML), if you write *semantically* using *the correct tool for the job*, then you can let SO take care of what is and isn't an appropriate way to render that post, both now and in future versions of the site.

<strike>I do make an exception in comments, where newlines don't exist and replying to the OP in a small, bunched-up space often needs to hit a little harder and faster than in an answer, so I will sometimes preface a comment with a quote from the OP in `this form`. It's not ideal.</strike> *[ed. I shan't be doing this any more.]*

Comment: I agree that backticks are not the correct tool for the job, but I still feel like I want similarly-styled inline-quotes (i.e. looks the same but no fixed-width to not upset your trigger finger =P ). I dunno, quoted italics don't look like quote blocks, it feels inconsistent and weird for me. Perhaps it's just me :-)

Comment: OCD is hardly an argument (or I would have a few hundred feature requests that I could insist on being implemented on that basis). You say you make an exception for comments because they're inherently single-line, but to me putting quotations in their own block is not always the right solution, so I "abuse" inline code in the same way as in comments. Of course, I'd love to have an "inline quote" feature, and would use it exclusively if it's introduced someday.

Comment: @yuvi: That would be a good feature, though I can also see _that_ being horribly abused. Sometimes the good old fashioned `"` is what you want; no need for garish colours, backgrounds and bolds emblazoned everywhere.

Comment: It will probably won't be abused more than backticks (which are being abused partly because they're so easy and short. `<q>` would require an actual effort. (and yes, it's an effort! I'm a web developer. For me, if I need to do anything more than `tagname+tab` it's an effort (that, or I'm using a bad editor)));

Comment: @yuvi: I'm sorry to hear that.

Comment: what? It's not bad. I can quit any time I want

Comment: Anyway, I'm marking your answer as correct. I think I'll get used to using italics-in-parenthesis. You raise similar points to those of @Boltclock, only his answer seems kinda angry. Also I think your answer expresses things more clearly (but it's mostly the anger thing).

Comment: @yuvi: I'm too hungover to be angry today

Comment: Not all of us are so obsessive.

Comment: @Cypher: You don't have to be "obsessive" to use the correct formatting for the task. Can't believe you downvoted me on that principle. I take it you've never published any document, then?

Comment: Sorry, don't take offense. I don't take Meta votes too seriously (agree/disagree sort of thing). When reading your answer, the message conveyed to me was that it's not "correct" and therefore invokes compulsive behaviors. With statements like "OCD hurt and my edit trigger finger twitch", "without getting a headache", and "shouldn't be forced on me", my impression is that the poster's behavior bothers you personally. That to me, isn't exactly a valid reason for anything. However, your last paragraph (about future rendering) is spot on. I agree in principal, just not on the main points written.

Comment: @Cypher: *shrug* I'm sure you wouldn't wRITE wORDS lIKE tHIS, bECAUSE it is not the _correct_ way to write English sentences. What I said in my answer is no different. It doesn't mean I'm being compulsive; it means I have eyes and I am capable of appreciating professional neatness in written communication. when someone is making SO posts "messy" then, yes, it bothers me personally. I wouldn't answer _anything_ on meta that didn't bother me personally; who would?

Comment: [Guillemets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillemet) are another possibility: «This». I like them for long quotes in comments because they are more visible than "".

Answer (score 17):

A `quotation` and an "inline code span" are two completely different things, There is no disputing this fact,

In much the same way that it is inappropriate {in English anyway} to end a sentence with a comma and separate two or more parts of a sentence with a period. it is also inappropriate to demarcate an inline quotation as an inline code span. unless you are quoting something that consists entirely of code,

In your answer. you are quoting a written statement from a piece of documentation, This statement is entirely in natural language. with no references to code, If you want to quote it inline. you should use quotation marks. which in English are represented as inverted commas. or in HTML. the "<q>" element. and not the "<code>" element {or its Markdown representation. backticks}, This is not just a matter of style. and I honestly cannot comprehend how anyone could possibly think that way,

Saying that backticks can be used to quote written prose inline is like saying that a code block can be used to quote written prose in a self-contained block {as opposed to. you know. using a "<blockquote>" element}, For example;

```
And that still makes a lot of sense to me. inline code is usually technical jargon or very short pieces of code you want to emphesize. If I want to use inline-quotes, it's usually the same situation (or I don't want to put it right before a code block so it won't be confusing).
```

This makes absolutely no sense to me whatsoever,

Comment: `This makes absolutely no sense to me whatsoever.` Well, it makes for me ;) I sometimes have to quote something inline, and it does the job (although I've been using italics more and more to do that lately).

Comment: If it's technical in nature (quoting a function definition) - doesn't it make as much sense as inline code? And what about putting quotes in comments, doesn't it make sense to use backticks?

Comment: Documentation is not programming code. Comments yes it's ugly but I admit I do that.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: It was deliberate. It started with me quoting that paragraph from the question using a code block to illustrate the comparison between using backticks for inline quotations, and code blocks for blockquotes (which, by the way, is also a thing real people do with real answers). Then it spread.

Comment: @BoltClock: Heh ok sorry

Answer (score 8):

I don't understand this. There is a well-known way to demarcate inline quotations in English: the quotation marks. Come on, just look at the name of those things.

If you want the quote to receive additional emphasis, use some emphasis markup, i.e. surround it with `*` in Markdown.

> (b) looks the same (there's no syntax highlighting in inline-code. I knew that beforehand).

It does not look the same. Text with code formatting usually renders in monospaced fonts, while quotation blocks don't change the font that way.

Comment: so maybe we should add `<q>` and then it won't be monospaced. quotations don't always do it (we wouldn't have a quote block otherwise)

Comment: There's no precedent for HTML-like "tags" to be defined by Markdown (though some HTML tags are inherited).

Comment: This opinion is also expressed on Meta.SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149464/159251

Answer (score 3):

In my view, this problem is created by the current blockquote formatting. The blockquotes do an admirable job of making it entirely clear that the quoted text is from a different source... the current yellow background, as well as the text being offset and inset, make it clear this is a separate source, and clearly in the StackOverflow context that source is the original question.

Good writers know that block quotes are only used for extended quotes, and that inline quotes should be used for shorter quotes that are integrated into the text. This is often the most efficient and effective way to explain a point.

However, the current formatting creates a major disconnect between block quotes and inline quotes. Block quotes receive special formatting, inline quotes do not. In formal writing (e.g., academic writing), both block quotes and inline quotes receive the accepted 'special formatting', which is normally a citation to the source of the quote. In StackOverflow, the formatting of the block quote essentially acts as this citation mechanism. However, in my view this actually serves to *disconnect* inline quotes from their source, as by omission they are not flagged as being quotes in this formal way. This is particularly acute with the StackOverflow design, where blockquotes have a clearly different yellow background (a style decision I prefer, but which exacerbates the issue).

When you see behaviour that you believe to be dysfunctional, it is always valuable to ask what the *functional* value of that behaviour is. People here rightly argue that inline code tags should not be used for marking out inline quotes. But the logical reason why people who are otherwise good contributors are doing this is because inline code tags provide text formatting that partially matches the blockquote formatting, and that using these tags thus presents answers that are less *visually* wrong than just using straight quote marks, because without a more formal explanation of the source of the "content contained within your quote marks" (Babbage, 2015), standard quote marks could mean almost anything.

Comment: If you're quoting someone on an SE site, you need a citation anyways, usually in the form of a link. The link will be in the immediate vicinity of the quotation. An exception would be where you're quoting part of the question to which you're responding, but that should be clear enough to not require further contextualization anyways,

Answer (score -14):

I have to disagree with Light in this specific case, as I personally believe using code formatting is fine for putting quotes inline, as you say and did.

I do so too from time to time, and would have left your answer alone.

However, in the general case, code formatting is indeed abused to highlight arbitrary words sometimes, and that usage should be edited.

Comment: "I do so too from time to time" I'm a bit busy at the moment so please go through your question history and change them to quotes yourself.

Comment: @Kevin, questions won't be a problem, answers will. Since one cannot search specifically for "abuse" of backticks and I have 2,500-odd answers, I estimate that work to be completed around 2022.

Comment: This is the correct answer, though obviously not the Meta-popular one.