# Why is this a terrible suggested edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, review-suspension

[image]

I've approved this suggested edit yesterday. While it is not a big improvement, at least it did make the types and class names stand out.

And today, I get this message when I try to review :

> This was a terrible suggested edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12182586 and should not have been approved. Please don't approve edits like this.
>
> Come back in 3 days to continue reviewing.

Can someone enlighten me, why is this a terrible suggested edit?

Comment: While in an ideal world you probably should have rejected this edit, I think the ban is a bit overly harsh for this issue.

Comment: @Ctx A 3-day review ban really isn't a harsh penalty.

Comment: I also got banned for the same question

Comment: A suggested edit which only introduces inline code or emphasis is never useful.

Comment: I can hardly believe that an official Stack Overflow message uses phrasing like that. I would've expected something more like "An edit you recently approved (link) was determined not to meet the quality standards set in the Help Center (link). Please check out the listed standards of a good edit and come back in three days to continue reviewing."

Comment: @Ctx: I understand where you're coming from, but over-zealous reviewers approving everything they see is a _huge_ problem at the moment. If we let every one slide with a "well you _shouldn't really_ have done that, but oh well..." then what's the point in the suggested edits system? Might as well just open it up. If it helps, see the ban as protecting the system rather than punishing the reviewer. After all, it's not like they're actually being locked up for three days in real life.

Comment: `pointer array of Service` is not code, and neither is `segmentation fault`, and they should not have been formatted as such. I am otherwise in complete agreement with you and with @TigerhawkT3

Comment: If you don't want people to make worthless edits, don't reward them to do so - I say ditch the 2 points low rep users get for editing. I've never thought that was a good idea.

Comment: @bjb568 Editing is specifically for fixing formatting issues.  Not only does it make it easier to read the question, it provides opportunities for new users to understand how they should have formatted the question.

Comment: @Trisped Of course. But suggested edits must be substantial and address multiple problems in the post.

Comment: @EJP `segmentation fault` is output.

Comment: @bjb568 Please provide a link detailing that.  The only instructions I can find are on the [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) page which mentions that only substantial edits should be included, but does not define it.  Since the formatting changes above are instantly recognizable and make the post easier to read, I consider them to be substantial.

Comment: @Trisped ["make your edits count, so that the new attention is brought to **something substantial** … Tiny, **trivial edits** are discouraged - try to make the post **significantly better** when you edit, correcting **all problems that you observe**."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) ["Your edit did not correct **critical issues** with the post"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238039/237813) [old guidance text](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/58120?m=18723903#18723903)

Comment: @bjb568 The editing page which is in your first link only indicates that the post should be significantly better (which the listed change is), and I did not see anything problems that were not fixed (not that problems I observer were observed by the editor).  The second link backs that trivial changes are not minor.  The third post is not relevant since it is not current guidance, but that also does not say that formatting changes are minor.  I am specifically asking why this case is not [substantial](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/substantial).

Comment: @Trisped I edited the post to demonstrate that there are other correctable things. The change did not make it better, it made it significantly and objectively worse by introducing errors and without correcting actual problems. Furthermore, the edit failed to address other problems in the post which obviously has substantial problems given its current score. Suggested edits should not, by community consensus and official guidelines, polish turds. This question is a turd. Suggested edits should address all significant problems with a post. The edit did not. You misinterpreted Shog's post.

Comment: @bjb568 [Shog9](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238039/295517)'s post is quite clear "_The meaning of "too minor" varies widely between individuals._"  I am not sure which post you edited, but the one in question  is pictured in the OP.  While the editor might not have seen all of the issues, and may have done them wrong, the changes they made are not too minor to warrant an edit because they make a [substantial](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/substantial) improvement.  Do you have evidence to contradict my assertion?

Comment: @Trisped [link to my edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36922052/6). You said "trivial changes are not minor", Shog did not. Shog's post (which was prompted by a discussion he had *with me*) details how the system was changed to crack down on minor edits and reviewers who systematically and incorrectly approve them by promoting "minor edit" to have an entire new process and button. Yes, I do have "evidence" to "contradict" your assertion, namely the comments that I just wrote that are more than just an unexplained link to a popular dictionary. Did you, perchance, read this "evidence"?

Comment: @bjb568 As I said, [Shog9](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238039/295517)'s post is quite clear "_The meaning of "too minor" varies widely between individuals. Are trivial changes always too minor, or only too minor when they ignore other, more damning problems with the post?_" He obviously thinks of them as different.  You have not provided any evidence of what is and is not considered minor.  I read all links and words in your comments to this question.  Feel free to pick your own dictionary.  The one I choose is top of my google search, but the others are the same.

Comment: @Trisped However much you may like to squabble over semantics, what you think "too minor" or "substantial" should mean has no relevance to the fact that Shog's post was about a change to *remove confusing wording* from the edit review guidance and make it clearer that minor edits *aren't* acceptable. The text you quoted serves as justification for this change and now "too minor" is not mentioned in the review text. Instead there is now a much better system for rejecting insubstantial edits. The policy with regard to minor edits never changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110867/discussion-between-trisped-and-bjb568).

Comment: @Trisped: Not when the edit makes the formatting _worse_, no. We don't want users to learn the wrong thing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit this conversation was moved to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110867/discussion-between-trisped-and-bjb568).  Please observe the rules and continue it there.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[I triggered this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278909/155739).

The user whose edit you approved had been making a whole ton of awful edits that added backticks to arbitrary phrases and even added signatures to other people's posts!

This was bad enough but the real problem was that a majority of his suggestions were being approved, a clear indication of criminally subpar reviewing that needed to be stopped.

I'd say you got a *little* unlucky here, being caught up in the clean-up when this edit wasn't as bad as the others. Most of the backticking is borderline acceptable — it's just the "pointer array of Service" and "segmentation fault" that absolutely should not have been backticked. Which does beg the question: what about this edit made you think you should accept it?

The message you're seeing is obviously a manually-constructed message from the helpful moderator who was left with little choice but to "hand out review bans like candy". Since your "punishment" is only a three-day review suspension, I propose that you go out and enjoy the sunshine for a bit, then come back later in the week ready to take a little more care with your reviewing.

Comment: Comments like this: `This was a terrible suggested edit: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12182586 and should not have been approved. Please don't approve edits like this.

Come back in 3 days to continue reviewing.`  Are pretty rude though.

Comment: @JonH: Really? I don't detect any rudeness. It's _firm_, sure, but that's necessary. We can't go through life expecting butterflies and unicorns at every turn. "Pretty rude" would be _"don't you f@cking dare accept a sh!t edit like that again, you little b@stard."_ I mean, he even said "please"! :)

Comment: @JonH Did you deliberately use code formatting in your comment? Please use code formatting for code and not for normal text.

Comment: @DavidPostill: ahaha

Comment: @JonH - I wrote that ban message, and I stand by it. I think the formatting change made the post worse, and should not have been approved. We have a limited amount of space to write in those, and I needed to convey the link to the edit. I did say "Please". The last sentence is inserted by the system based on the ban term, which I set at 3 days since this was on a Friday and most people don't review over the weekend. I wanted to make sure it was seen. All other reviewers were banned for longer, because they had repeatedly failed audits and clearly were not paying attention.

Comment: @DavidPostill Considering there's no way to quote text in comments, and " are not exactly noticeable, code blocks to denote a quote is perfectly fine. There is nothing about the formatting that indicates it's for code other than the name.

Comment: @Rob: FWIW [I've settled on _"formatting like this"_](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262463/quoted-text-inline-with-the-rest-using-code-tags-is-bad-why#comment52739_262463) which seems to work pretty well.

Answer (score 101):

To expand on [Flexo's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322099), let's take a closer look at what the specific [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12182586) actually changed:

1. It added backticks around the words "Service", "Court" and "Machine" in this sentence:

   > I have abstract class (Service) with two derived classes (Court and Machine).

   These words are (presumably) class names, which are a bit of a borderline case: some users like to always mark them up as code, others prefer to leave them unformatted when they appear merely as names in prose, and not as part of an actual code fragment.  Personally, I'd normally respect the original author's choice and not edit them either way, nor would I approve an edit that *only* added (or removed) backticks around class names.  Still, if the *rest of the edit* was good, I also wouldn't reject just because of a detail like this.

   (The edit also removed the parentheses, which is another stylistic choice.  To me, the sentence seems readable with or without them, which again means that I would not personally edit them, but I also wouldn't reject an otherwise good edit just for doing so.)
2. It added backticks around "a pointer array of Service" in:

   > I also have a pointer array of Service, and [...]

   **This is unquestionably wrong.**  The phrase "a pointer array of Service" is *not* code, at least not in any programming language I know of, but merely a prose description of a data structure.  Just adding backticks around the class name "Service" *might* have been valid (and certainly should have been done for consistency, if the earlier mentions of class names were also backticked), but there's no excuse (other than ignorance or inattentiveness, that is) for marking up "a pointer array" as code.
3. It added backticks around "if" in:

   > I'm using an if.

   This is the *only* part of the edit that I would consider (marginally) useful, because without code markup, the keyword `if` looks confusingly like the English conjunction "if", making the sentence potentially difficult to parse.  Granted, in this particular case, the meaning seems clear enough even without the backticks.
4. It replaced quotes with backticks around "segmentation fault" in:

   > I receive a "segmentation fault" and [...]

   If you consider the quotes around "segmentation fault" to imply that it's a direct quotation of an error message, then this change might *almost* be considered valid: one of the valid uses for code markup is for verbatim program output, especially if it contains actual code fragments (like error messages often do) or otherwise is formatted in a way that makes it more readable in a monospace font (and/or as a preformatted text block).

   Still, in the particular case, I don't think that reasoning applies.  Not only is "segmentation fault" a perfectly valid phrase in English prose text, describing a certain type of runtime error, but even if it *was* a direct quote, it still doesn't contain any embedded code or anything else that would benefit from the monospace styling.

It's also worth briefly noting a few things that the edit did *not* do:

- It didn't add the missing indefinite article into "I have abstract class [...]".
- It didn't capitalize (or, for that matter, add consistent backticks to) the class names in "both court and machine".
- It didn't fix the run-on sentence by (e.g.) replacing the comma after "machine" [sic] with a full stop.  (In this case, the comma is clearly wrong both grammatically and stylistically.)
- It also didn't fix the run-on sentence in the next paragraph (e.g.) by replacing the "and" after "segmentation fault" with a full stop.  (This is a more borderline case, since the original is at least grammatically valid, but I'd still consider a sentence break here a significant improvement.)

In short, **the edit did (almost) nothing to improve the post**, while the changes it *did* do were either actively harmful (backticking "a pointer array of Service") or were (at best) neutral style changes that disagreed with the original author's perfectly valid stylistic choices.  In other words, the edit as a whole was slightly harmful, and mostly useless, with no real redeeming features.

You *might* legitimately disagree with some of this, if you're one of those people who strongly prefers to see class names marked as code.  Even then, though, the suggested edit is at best incomplete, and partly just plain wrong.  I could see picking the "Edit" option in review (as Josh KG eventually did, although [their further edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36922052/revisions) really didn't improve things much at all) and fixing the remaining issues with the post, but certainly not accepting the suggested edit as is.

Also, even if you really, *really* like to use backticks for class names, it's important to note that others do disagree, and that for such legitimately controversial style choices, it's generally best to avoid needless editing and to respect the original author's choice even if it doesn't match your own personal preference.

Comment: This. Literally the _only_ thing this editor did was putting things in code markdown. And in at least one case the editor was flat-out _wrong_ to do so. This type of editor often does these useless/harmful edits in sprees. Which is one more reason to Reject where you might otherwise Skip - discourage sprees of bad edits.

Comment: It also didn't remove the 'Thank you very much :)` noise at the end of the text (but should have done).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Good catch. I only looked at the Markdown diff, which didn't show that.

Comment: This is a very well-explained dissection of what went right and what went wrong in the suggested edit. I'm thankful for such dedicated people like you in the SO community

Comment: I agree with basically all of this. The only way this answer fails is that it entirely misses the context of the review ban, which is [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278909/155739).

Answer (score 56):

The edit seems to largely introduce backticks, which are used for *code markup* for things that aren't code. That's wrong and makes the post worse, not better.

Comment: In fairness to the OP, about half of the backticks are for object names, which are essentially code, and the others seems to be borderline.  And edit ban for something like this seems overly harsh, unless there is more of a history of poor edit approvals.

Comment: Isn't it how inlined type name is supposed to be formatted? At least, that is how I've learned from other questions, like : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords-in-java/8881376#8881376

Comment: @Xiaoy312 - No. Some people do it out of personal preference but you aren't required to format a class name, keyword, or variable as code in the middle of normal text. Since there are a few users who are known to make edits like this (re-formatting that's nothing but personal preference) in order to troll other users, it's better to reject edits like this.

Comment: @Xiaoy312 That would apply to the edits to the first paragraph, but not the edits to the following two.

Comment: @Servy while I agree that using backticks for the 2nd and 3rd paragraphs are not optimal, the items that did get back ticks were not horrible.  One of them items was an operator (an if statement) and an error message and what appears to be a description of an object.  It is not a good edit, but hardly one I would say is worth banning someone.

Comment: *It is not a good edit, but hardly one I would say is worth banning someone.* @psubsee2003 - I don't have access to the edit review queue (yet?) but do they score edits that way? I assumed that edits, like posts, were either good or bad.

Comment: @BSMP edits are not scored at all, they are either approved by the reviewers or not.  There are dozens upon dozens bad edits that get approved every day, some are really terrible, and some are just meh.  If moderators are going to go and levy manual review bans (and that is what this one was), it shouldn't be subjective - it should be truly terrible.  The only part we don't know is if there is a more extensive history of poor edit decisions by the OP that might have justified a ban.

Comment: There are exactly zero of these backticks that are valid

Comment: "Pointer array of Service" isn't code, but a description of code. That's the deal breaker, where it turns from a pointless edit into a "Lyme disease edit." Either way it should be rejected, it does not improve the post in any way.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: I very definitely disagree. Every use of a class name in there seems entirely reasonable to me, is how I would format my own post, and I'd be very cross if someone took them out. I agree that "Pointer array of Service" shouldn't have been in backticks, nor "Segmentation fault" but the ones in the very first sentence seem entirely reasonable to me, and helpful. I do find it interesting that the formatting help talks about the mechanics of formatting, but not when it's appropriate. Maybe some community consensus would be useful.

Comment: It's official. Jon Skeet has approved the edit suggestion. So cancel the review ban already!

Comment: @JonSkeet exactly - I'd do the formatting you describe. As it stands, some people like putting class names in monospace, and edit them in to make posts clearer, and others don't like it, and ban people for approving edits that do it. BSMP for some reason thinks one of those is trolling and the other isn't. Can't say I agree in the slightest.

Comment: I consider the code markdown for class names the same as changing American English to British English or vice versa. Stick to the OP's preference. So even without the "Pointer array of Service" it counts as "No improvement whatsever".

Comment: why wasn't the blocking admin further blocked for making such a vague "why you were blocked" comment?

Comment: *BSMP for some reason thinks one of those is trolling* @RobertGrant - I never said anything like that. I said that [there are instances of users using edits to troll others](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265571/approved-suggested-edit-from-a-known-troll), not that this specific instance was trolling. There's a difference between saying that something happens and saying that something is happening now.

Comment: @user1663987 The moderator did the right thing. Reviewers are supposed to understand what good and bad edits are _before_ they start reviewing. That being said, it does credit to the reviewer that they explain why they approved it and look for clarification.

Comment: @S.L.Barth given this issue was partially a personal style choice, but more importantly that the moderator blocked a reviewer with no explanation of why ("the edit was bad"), and that it therefore led to this whole discussion and the involvement of almost 700 people, how is what the moderator did better than accepting the original edit? How will the moderator learn to leave better feedback unless someone blocks them and they have to start a thread like this? As a simple user, that moderator does not fill me with confidence at making the site better vs ticking off moderators, which are needed.

Comment: @AlexJolig: That's an appeal to popularity with no basis in logic. Jon Skeet is just a human being, like you and me.

Comment: @user1663987 It would be great if the moderators could leave more personalized guidance when suspending a reviewer. But the sheer size of Stack Overflow doesn't allow that. There are far too many bad reviews every day. That's an old, old problem with review.

Comment: @S.L.Barth understood. I've heard many times that moderators and reviewers are very busy. As an aside, my next thought is: Therefore, efficiently use the ones that exist and don't block them for personal style choices, etc. least they become ticked off, etc etc etc. Moderators should be supporting reviewers and helping them to get work done, like a good project manager, and not like power corrupt dictators.

Comment: @user1663987: Calling this moderator a "power corrupt dictator" for giving a three-day suspension over a poor edit review is far worse behaviour than anyone else involved in this situation (except, arguably, the original editor). The moderator is literally doing his job, and doing it well. Don't want a suspension? Don't approve harmful edits. Fairly straightforward, that!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I can accept your statement only while also discarding any future claims I read about how busy moderators are, if they're going to drive reviewers away,

Comment: You say you want feedback from moderators. Review bans for bad reviews (with a link to an example) are exactly that. Often that's all the feedback required. The alternative is to see something problematic and take no action to use it as a learning point. Sometimes the feedback could be clearer, or touches on a bigger point. Then it ends up here on meta. Could it be slicker? I'm sure it could and constructive feedback or feature requests are gladly received, but it's hardly deliberately driving people away or abuse of power.

Comment: @user1663987: Huh? This isn't driving reviewers away. This is making it clear what job reviewers should be doing, and how they should be doing it. If some reviewers - and I'm certain this is not the common outcome - see this and instead of going "okay I'll review properly" go "I will stop reviewing", then _the system is working_. This is moderation _doing its job_! Stack Overflow is not a primary school game in which "everyone gets to review". Do it properly or don't. This is literally the reason we have moderators. Ta :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What part of "This was a terrible suggested edit" is clear or tells the reviewer what they should be doing? None. How does a 3 day ban help the reviewer to accomplish or learn anything? It doesn't.

Comment: @user1663987: _"This was a terrible suggested edit"_ declares, in no uncertain terms, the facts of the situation. (What's unclear about it?) _"Please don't approve edits like this"_ This tells the reviewer what they should be doing. (Again, how did you miss that?) _"How does a 3 day ban help the reviewer to accomplish or learn anything? It doesn't."_ Like any suspension or imprisonment in the entirety of human society, it's a deterrent. If you don't "punish" people for doing the wrong thing, they will keep doing the wrong thing. And, honestly, a 3-day review ban is hardly a punishment. Chill.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I completely disagree with your claims and use this question as counter-evidence, but I sense you are very close minded about this and feel you know better, so I abandon this topic. Your further attempt at manipulation by telling me to "chill" suggests you already play power games to your advantage, so there is no point.

Comment: @user1663987: You are certainly entitled to your opinion, but you're _not_ entitled to make personal attacks like "you are very close minded about this and feel you know better", or "you play power games to your advantage". Feel free to ping me again when you're ready to behave like an adult. Until that time, please resist the urge to address any further comments to me. Cheers!

Answer (score 10):

Neither answer so far makes an issue of it, but the removal of the parentheses degrades the grammar. If you wanted to remove them and maintain correct grammar, you would have to add articles or other elements. E.g.,

> I have **an** abstract class **named** `Service` with two derived classes **:** `Court` and `Machine`.

Or something similar. Just plopping the names in those spots without the parentheses is awkward at best, grammatically incorrect at worst. (I suspect the latter, although I wouldn't be able to cite rules for it.) The parentheses serve to indicate to the read that the sentence is providing extra, not-strictly-necessary information in a non-grammatical place and separates it from the flow of the actual sentence. You might could use commas, but you definitely need *something*.

Comment: `an` should have been there from the start, regardless of the parentheses. Otherwise, a code block signifies the same as the parentheses - there is no real difference. "I have an abstract class `Service`" is just as (in?)valid as it was with parentheses. If you want to be technical, though, they should be in quotes if we're worried about grammar.

Comment: This is not French, so you should use 'THIN SPACE' (U+2009) before the colon (or no space at all).

Comment: @transistor09 I was ensuring the colon would be bolded correctly. =p The space is extraneous.

Comment: I was going to comment on that too (though I would have suggested commas before and after "Service", etc.). I would consider backticks equivalent to quotes, not parenthesis.