# What do I need to do reenable myself to suggest edits?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, edit-ban

I have been banned from suggesting edits, and it says:

> You are temporarily banned from suggesting edits - please review your
>   edit history.

But if you go through that I can see the summary as:

> piyush jaiswal had 66 edit suggestions approved, and 22 edit
>   suggestions rejected

I got some strong comments from Lightness Races in Orbit, may be that's the case I am banned, but when will this ban be lifted?

Comment: Instead of wondering when your ban will expire, maybe you should actually read the comments and find out what behavior caused the ban. Clearly you were doing something wrong.

Comment: Yes, your suggested edits are terrible, the comments from Lightness are correct, and those edits are rejected correctly. [Review everything here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5469991/piyush-jaiswal?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). Most of what is approved should have been rejected as well. The reviewers haven't been very helpful to you.

Comment: I have realized now that editing 'everything" doesn't make any sense until we "add some value" to it, but now thats past, can i know when the ban will be lifted, as i am pretty much sure that i can add value with my suggested edits

Comment: `code` syntax is for CODE. Only for code. Not for normal words. Not for trademarks/names. Not for anything. Except code.

Comment: Also, do not add text like *"Any help will be appreciated"*. In fact, if you see such text while suggesting an edit, you should remove it.

Comment: Okay points noted @Mat

Comment: Okay points noted @Stijn

Comment: @piyushjaiswal the ban lifts in 2 days - use that time to fully understand what kind of edits you should and should not be making.

Comment: @JonClements thanks for the info, yes i will utilize this time to understand the rules and regulation for suggesting edits

Comment: A while ago, I [proposed a FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303219/812149) for editors. Various people have contributed to it. It is not official, but I believe you may find it helpful.

Comment: @piyushjaiswal IMO consider edits as contribution to cleanup the site and  not as a tool for rep mining. When you reach 2k , you'd stop receiving reps on edits and you will find out that quality questions and answers are the only way to increase your reputation and earn badges.

Comment: @Vin yes, got your point too...

Comment: @piyushjaiswal this question has been asked so many times here.. just search for it & you would have got the answer.

Answer (score 8):

Prepare for a shock... one of your edit suggestions became the subject of heated discussion [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322098/why-is-this-a-terrible-suggested-edit).
Which may have been the reason your edit suggestions came to the attention of the moderators.

Most of what needs to be said has already been said in comments. But since comments are volatile, I'll summarize them here for future readers.

- Code markdown should be used for code, not for emphasis.
- Things like "thanks in advance" should be removed from posts, not added.

I'd like to point out that emphasis should be used sparingly. You could have used **boldface** or *italics* for the things you put in `code markdown`, but as a reviewer I would have rejected most of that. Boldface and italics are meant to draw extra attention to something. If many parts of a post are asking for extra attention... then nothing will get extra attention.

There is no way to get rid of an edit suspension, one just has to sit it out.

To prevent edit suspensions in the future, you may want to edit slowly. If an edit suggestion is rejected, then the next time you suggest an edit you will get a warning. By keeping a slow pace, you can see this feedback, which may help you hone your editing skills.

To be fair, the reviewers have something to answer for too. We have a lot of people who happily approve every edit suggestion they encounter, simply to get their Steward badge as fast as they can. In doing so, they gave you the wrong feedback.
For this reason, it may be useful to check even on edit suggestions that got approved. You can see if there were Reject votes in addition to the Approve votes, which may also give you feedback.

Comment: I did try to let OP know about the Meta discussion [in a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36860146/invalid-identifier-error-in-oracle/36860326#comment61454987_36860326) a few days ago.

Comment: Minor detail, but it actually started here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278909/notify-users-when-their-approved-suggested-edit-is-rolled-back and was brought to our attention by a number of flags on these edits.

Comment: Ohh i never thought in my wild imagination that this would have happened.....sorry for everything