# 'Incorrect review' shown when the same edit has been approved by others?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits, review-suspension

I reviewed an edit on Stack Overflow. I approved the edit. And in the log it seems that the same edit has been approved by others as well. But, it is showing that is has been reviewed incorrectly.

> You have made too many incorrect reviews. For an example of a task you
>   should have reviewed differently, see:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12857300

Can anybody tell me why this was so?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is *not* an audit - you have been banned manually for reviewing by a ♦ moderator. While formatting class names like UIButton as `UIButton` is allowed in edits, one should ***never*** do this for normal words like `implementation`<sup>1</sup>. The suggested edit *does* leave a lot of grammatical errors in the post, so the correct review action would have been

> **No improvement whatsover**
>
> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

or, equally valid, <kbd>Reject and Edit</kbd> and improving the post yourself, concentrating on the grammar issues.

<sup>1</sup><sub>: yes, `@implementation` is a keyword in Objective-C, but that was not what was meant here.</sub>

Comment: Thanks. This clarifies my doubt. also does this mean the others who approved the edit also got banned ?

Comment: @AnirudhaAgashe I would assume so, but it could be that this ban was handed out based on more than one of these kind of reviews. The moderator in case would have to confirm.

Comment: @AnirudhaAgashe: yes, the moderator handed out more review bans, you were not the only one.

Comment: @AnirudhaAgashe I am one of the others who approved the edit, and just noticed the same ban. On a closer look I can see why that was questionable (e.g. [Why is this a terrible suggested edit?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322098/why-is-this-a-terrible-suggested-edit)). While I appreciate the reasons behind it, I am somewhat puzzled that the reviews were flagged, yet the edit itself has (so far) not been rolled back.

Comment: @dxiv I did not roll back the edit, but I removed the back ticks from `implementation` and I fixed the grammar issues.