# Strange behavior in review status

Tags: support, review-suspension

I got an error of `too many incorrect reviews`, and as example I got this review:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13119671
which was *approved* by all 3 reviewers (including me).

The edit was suggested on a question and it wasn't rejected by any mod (as far as I could tell).

[image]
Any ideas what is going on there?

Comment: When that happens it means that the approval was manually reverted by a diamond mod, who can also trigger a ban)

Comment: @Patrice It wasn't reverted.

Comment: @Laurel well no, [it was a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558385/reduce-compile-and-deployment-time-in-android-studio-when-debugging)

Comment: @AndrewMedico didnt check much (from a phone atm). I guess the mod didnt revert the edit, but possibly flagged the edit as "shouldnt have been approved" which, again, can trigger a ban.

Comment: Given the situation, it seems you were manually banned by a moderator for approving an edit (or maybe many edits) that shouldn't have been approved.  The post in question is a good example of a worthless edit.  It didn't make the post worse, but really didn't make it better either and added some unnecessary noise (e.g. "Any suggestions?").  Flipping through your recent suggested edit reviews, you have a number of very borderline edits (such as http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13190514) that probably shouldn't have been approved.  I'm guessing the mod felt the same way.

Comment: @psubsee2003, thank you for your reply! I think that if a moderator took an action against someone it should be mentioned in some way (otherwise it's impossible to learn/change behavior). I agree that the "any suggestions" shouldn't be there, however I do think that the change of the title is good. As for the second link - it is a formatting edit, which makes the code much more readable so I really don't think such edit shouldn't have been approved.

Comment: @Dekel no one except the mod that banned you can say exactly why and if it was just the one linked post, or if was based on a history.  But I have seen this method in the past to get the attention of an individual and make them ask the question as to why (I'm not sure how much specific feedback mods can provide in the ban message - I think it might be a canned message that can't be edited save the example review link.

Comment: @psubsee2003, is there a place someone can check to see if this really is a ban or is it something else? My main concern is that "it seems like" is not really a creditable source, and I'm trying to figure out if it's a bug or something else, because if a moderator took an action - I think it should be mentioned somewhere and someone should be able to have access to such action.

Comment: @Dekel ok, I will stop hedging - you were manually banned by a moderator.  See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327227/incorrect-review-shown-when-the-same-edit-has-been-approved-by-others  (and the chain of duplicates behind it).  All of the users had the same message and all were manually banned by a mod.

Comment: I manually banned you. [The review to which you linked](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13119671) was extremely trivial, added the unnecessary "Any suggestions?", and did nothing substantive to improve the post in question. [This "answer"](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13181398) was a link-only answer and more a comment on other answers than an answer in itself. You could have flagged it, but you should not have approved a trivial edit. [This edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13181297) changes code and should be rejected. And so on.