# When constructive edits are allowed?

Tags: discussion

In the last few days, I've observed that *some user* just over edits posts even though it doesn't make the post any better and adds no extra meaning to the post. This users behavior is same on every question that they edit, and they try to edit each and every question. Even when their edit is rolled back, they try to edit the post again and again. This user has also been banned from the site once before for this behavior.

As an example:

1. [image]
2. Post Contains XML and question is all around the XML design still the removal of the tag is approved.

[image]

Here is what I want to know:

1. How much editing to a post is welcomed?
2. How can we stop this user from editing repeatedly even after being rolled back?
3. How can I flag this user for their behavior?

**EDIT**

As @Makoto suggested Flag to the question works. Moderator rolled back the edit and suspended user for 24 hours (*I thought this is end of the story user learned the lesson*) **BUT Now** from today as the suspension period ends user is same no change. This is more annoying than it was before.

[image]

So, What we can do else than the flags ?

Comment: That user no longer receives points for edits. They're well over the rep limit for that. Their edits don't go into the review queue, either. Also, in that particular edit, it seems the main goal was to remove the [android-studio] tag, which many would say is perfectly acceptable, since the issue is not with the IDE. The first edit there is not great, and should've been rejected/improved. Editing only to add the odd code highlighting is negligible improvement. They did nothing to fix the capitalization, correct the grammar, remove the "Thanks", etc.

Comment: @MikeM., I'm changing the example may be what would be helpful.

Comment: Yeah, that one's pretty pointless, too. I have no idea why users do that, but if we were to flag every user who edits to add incorrect/unnecessary code highlighting, the mods would drown from just the [android] tag. The problem is that users get these kinds of edits approved all the time when they're still <2000 (or whatever the cutoff is), so they continue to think they're correct and appropriate. Reviewers need to be rejecting these outright, stop the problem early, but that's never going to happen.

Comment: @MikeM.,`Reviewers need to be rejecting these outright, stop the problem early, but that's never going to happen` that's the reason this user just edits everything and most of the time meaningless. It's difficult for mods to check for users like this but is their way we can warn them ?

Comment: Warn whom? The users? You can @username ping anybody who edits a post, but don't be surprised if they ignore your advice.

Comment: @MikeM. , Yes to that user; but they wont understand the meaning of edit feature. In brief, i guess i need to have patience that they will change their behavior (commenting everywhere,editing everything).

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, and perhaps my possibly superfluous edits, but what is the harm in these edits? I try to make edits that I feel improve legibility of the overall post and that might include code highlighting.

Comment: @SilentRevolution: look at the top edit screenshot. Does that look like that editor "highlighted code"? It's the most annoying abuse of `code` ticks that I `can` think of. As for yours, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18172150) you highlighted the code correctly but failed to fix obvious grammar mistakes and removing the "thanks".

Comment: This is **not** a constructive edit. [Abusing code syntax](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990/1048572) for highlighting normal words [is plain wrong](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262463/1048572)

Comment: I've seen a 10k+ user with 50k+ post edits consisting almost entirely of pointless edits. And by "I've seen", I mean "I discovered it when a random post of mine was edited to change 'javascript' to 'JavaScript' and things like that." Their suggested edits history was similarly filled with pointless edits. I'm not really sure a few rejections stop people like this.

Comment: @Bergi, I Agree; Is there any way to stop people from doing this? because many are here who would like to introduce something (_some feature or anything_) that will prevent user from doing same over again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pick a post of theirs that they've made recently, flag *it*, and link to an edit screen like this, explaining in detail to moderators what the behavior is and what they're doing.  Edits like this are superfluous, don't improve anything, and genuinely aren't welcome.

Their past behavior doesn't matter; we don't really hold grudges on the site.  I'd just leave it to mods to sort 'em out.

Comment: That's a good approach to deal with. but What I'm not getting is why this edits are being approved by reviewer every time. I've around 30 photos of this user for his superfluous behavior.

Comment: Doesn't matter.  Flag it.  The moderator can figure out the history from there.  They'll be dealt with.

Comment: @Dipalis. That user is short of 10k which means that those edits won't be send to the review queue first, i.e. they aren't subject to any review any more.

Comment: @altocumulus, although user is around 10k they still does this and that's what is most annoying.

Comment: @Dipalis. Totally agreed. That's even aggravating the entire issue. I just wanted to point out why there are no more regular checks inhibiting this behavior. I am afraid the answer has to be: because we trust them...

Comment: @altocumulus, There should be something else than this `because we trust them...` because sometimes well reputed people(they get banned for the same once but they ain't learning from that too) actually need to learn _(Gaining trust from the site is all about being more meticulous in future.)_

Comment: My opinion is while reputation gives you the ability to do things, being able to skip checks and balances shouldn't be based on reputation.  That should only be based on your success rate with that tool.  I.e. reputation gives you ability to edit, but only a good ratio and enough of a baseline of approved edits would give you ability to skip review.

Comment: @AaronLS:  No further pontification is required.  If you see someone abusing their privileges, inform the moderators of it.

Comment: @Makoto A user's reputation indicates they have provided well received questions and answers.  It doesn't in any way indicate they are making quality edits.  So it doesn't make sense to bypass checks and balances such as edit reviews based on their reputation.  It's absolutely the wrong metric to use as a gating threshold.

Comment: @AaronLS:  Again, we don't need to pontificate this any further.  If someone's abusing their status, then moderators need to get involved.  I am ***not*** entertaining a philosophical discussion on this matter right now.

Comment: @Makoto I agree that a moderator would need to get involved in the current situation, but a change of mechanics would move towards a preventative approach rather than a reactive approach that consumes moderator resources and cleanup after the fact.  There's a saying that goes something like "I object to doing what computers can do."  Anyhow, you are welcome to abstain from further discussion if you consider it too philosophical to pontificate further.  I personally think my proposal is very practical in nature, rather than philosophical.

Comment: @Dipalis. Reputation is primarily a measure of participation in the site, not an indicator that everything they say or do is correct. Only consistent and blatantly bad behavior will prevent a user from continuing to earn reputation, unfortunately.

Comment: @jpmc26, well is there anything other than flag to stop users from doing this superfluous edits? I guess this feature is required.

Comment: @Dipalis. How can a computer system decide between superfluous and meaningful? [I've argued before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294026/1394393) that even something as small as capitalizing a word can be a *good* edit. It depends strongly on the context.

Comment: @jpmc26, If user is getting banned for his edits twice or thrice. Then check the history and stop them from editing at least or anything that can be possible and meaningful.

Comment: @jpmc26 It is not necessary to evaluate the content of the edit.  Instead the user only gains the ability to bypass the edit queue when they have a sufficient ratio of approved:rejected edits, weighted towards more recent edits.  This indicates they are editing consistently within community standards.

Comment: @Makoto, what you have suggested was pretty good. user get banned and after end of suspension period user is same. now I don't think flag is the appropriate.